# Performing jquery.get() function in VB.net

Tags: jquery, vb.net

I am trying to send HTTP GET request to the IP address with the parameter "pin" and value "12", then execute the function

```
 $.get("http://192.168.4.1:80/", {pin:12});
```

this code is in jquery and it is working fine on web server.

However, I am trying to develop a program using VB to achieve the same task. I know the code for GET request in VB but how do i send the parameter "pin" along with the request?

I wish to get a response like below same as the response using jquery:

```
+IPD,0,345:GET /?pin=12 HTTP/1.1
Host: 192.168.4.1
Connection: keep-alive
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is right your petition:

```
+IPD,0,345:GET /?pin=12 HTTP/1.1
Host: 192.168.4.1
Connection: keep-alive
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,
```

The parameters in a get request are sending in the URL so it would be the same to do:

```
$.get("http://192.168.4.1:80/", {pin:12});
```

And

```
$.get("http://192.168.4.1:80/?pin=12");
```

This means that you can do your request as you know in VB.NET but you must put in the host:

```
http://192.168.4.1:80/?pin=12
```

Comment: Thanks alot. It is working but my program crash after one try. Is there any problem in it? Sorry i am new to VB.
`Dim webClient As New System.Net.WebClient`

Comment: `Dim result As String = webClient.DownloadString("http://192.168.0.34:80/?pin=12")`

Comment: I supossed you are getting an exception in webClient.DownloadString, may I know what the exception is? You must see the exception in console if you are using visual studio

Comment: How do i see the exception?

Comment: If you have your project in visual studio you can press the play button, in the console you will see everything that is executing (if you write in console, etc.) Then if your application crash for some reason you would see the exception message in the same console.

Comment: It is just not responding without showing any error. I have to manually press the stop button in visual studio to close it

Comment: So there could be two things: your application is waiting for an answer from 192.168.4.1:80 or you have a loop somewhere else in  your code.

Comment: Ok. thx i got it already. The program is waiting for an answer but in my case i didnt need it so i just have to do response.abort and it is working fine now. Thanks alot!

Comment: Just an advice, it is important to always receive an answer in your http requests for example 200 OK, take into account that for some reason if you send a request and your server side fails (because it is shut down or there are a problem in your code) then the client side wouldn't be able that something went wrong and wouldn't be able to manage the exception.

Comment: Thank for your advice. I will try to improve it :D